# Proof for sequence $a_n$ with accumulation points $0$ and $2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I tried answering the following question, do my arguments make sense and are they correct?

> Suppose we have a sequence $a_n$ with positive terms and accumulation points $0$ and $2$.
>
> We consider the new sequence, $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$:
>
> $$ b_n= \frac{n+a_n}{n \cdot a_n}$$

I am now asked to answer the questions:

(a) give an accumulation point of $b_n$

Well, notice that:
$$ b_n= \frac{n+a_n}{n \cdot a_n}=\frac{1}{a_n} + \frac{1}{n}$$
In the limit for large $n$, we have that $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$. We notice that $a_n$ has a subsequence that converges to $2$, then certainly we have that $b_n$ has a subsequence $b_{n_j}$:
$$ b_{n_j}=\frac{1}{a_{n_j}} + \frac{1}{{n_j}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}+0$$
So $\frac{1}{2}$ is an accumulation point.

(b) Is $b_n$ bounded?

Notice that we have subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that converges to $0$, we now consider $b_{n_k}$, such that:
$$ b_{n_k}=\frac{1}{a_{n_k}} + \frac{1}{n_k}\rightarrow \infty $$
Because the sequence $b_n$ has a subsequence that is divergent to $\infty$, it cannot be bounded $\square$.

Comment: You cannot leave $\frac 1n$ as is when taking subsequences. Otherwise, the arguments are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argumentation seems to be correct.

I would just caution you to be a little more careful with notation.

How is $a'_n$ being labeled? Do the subindices coincide when passing to $b'_n$?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: I think it is better !